# node-gyp out-of-source build

Tags: node-gyp, gyp

Pretty simple. Node-gyp constructs 'build' folder right near sources. Is there a way to do out-of-source builds, i.e. relocate that folder somewhere else? I don't want my source tree polluted with build junk, nor do I want to copy sources manually somewhere. There's a hint when it runs, -Goutput_dir='.' though I couldn't find any mentions in both GYP and node-gyp docs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself. It seems that node-gyp has its output and some other folders being hard-nailed, without a way to change them, except modifying scripts by hand. No out-of-source builds then.